# calling google places api

Tags: android

```
//here is my code
public void performSearch() throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.println("Perform Search ....");
            System.out.println("-------------------");
            HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(transport);
            HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory.buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));
            request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
            request.getUrl().put("location", latitude + "," + longitude);
            request.getUrl().put("radius", 500);
            request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");

            if (PRINT_AS_STRING) {
                System.out.println(request.execute().parseAsString());
                Log.d("--->",request.execute().parseAsString());
            } else {

                PlacesList places = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
                System.out.println("STATUS = " + places.status);
                for (Place place : places.results) {
                    System.out.println(place);
                    Log.d("--->",place.toString());
                }
            }


        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getResponse().parseAsString());
            throw e;
        }
    }
    public static HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(final HttpTransport transport) {

          return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
           public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
            GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
            headers.setApplicationName("MyLocationHelper");
            request.setHeaders(headers);
           JsonHttpParser parser = null;
            parser.getJsonFactory();
           request.addParser(parser);
           }
        });
    }
```

I want to develop an application to show my current location on map and than i want to search the near by places around me. at this stage i am able to draw my current location on map, but i am unable to get the response from google places api.

performSearch() methods makes a call to google places api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following link: -> their usage of HTTP request + JSON parsing works

[Parsing Google Places JSON data in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549993/parsing-google-places-json-data-in-android)